# how to show a list view with images in a fragment in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment with 4 tabs, in one tab i need to show a listview.  I have got this far on my code but have a couple errors and i'm not sure if i'm just not doing it right or if i'm missing something simple.  Here is my code that i'm using

fragment activity

```
public class SupportFragment extends SherlockFragment{
String[] supporters = new String[] {
        "Gulf Shores",
        "Central",
        "Spanish Fort",
        "Jackson Heights",
        "Summerdale",
        "Atlas",
        "Robertsdale",
        "Eastern Shore"
};

int[] images = new int[] {
        R.drawable.gulfshores,
        R.drawable.central,
        R.drawable.spanishfort,
        R.drawable.jacksonheights,
        R.drawable.summerdale,
        R.drawable.atlas,
        R.drawable.robertsdale,
        R.drawable.easternshore
};

String[] church = new String[]{
        "Chruch of Christ",
        "Chruch of Christ",
        "Chruch of Christ",
        "Chruch of Christ",
        "Chruch of Christ",
        "Chruch of Christ",
        "Chruch of Christ",
        "Chruch of Christ"
};


 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_support_layout, null);


     List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("sup", "Supporters : " + supporters[i]);
            hm.put("chur","Church : " + church[i]);
            hm.put("icon", Integer.toString(images[i]) );
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        String[] from = {"sup", "chur", "icon"};

        int[] to = {R.id.icon, R.id.sup, R.id.chur};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        return root;

 }



 }
```

I am getting an error on these two lines of code from this

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);
```

and

```
 ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

the error i'm getting is:

The method getBaseContext() is undefined for the type SupportFragment

The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type SupportFragment

xml for listview

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/tableback" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the listview layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

any help you can give is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a `FragmentActivity` you have a `Fragment`, so of course you can't get the Context with `getBaseContext()`, you have to use `getActivity()` instead. 
You also have to inflate a View to use `findViewById`, if you want to do that in a Fragment.  However if you want to use Tabs you need a `FragmentActivity` which hadels your `Fragments`.

You can inflate a View like this in your fragments `onCreateView()` method:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myLayout, null);
```

Then you can call `findViewById` like this:

```
[...]view.findViewById(...);
```

Comment: your right i don't know why i said fragment activity, the getActivity() worked to solve that error but i'm not 100% sure on how i need to inflate the view to use the findViewById.  I'm not even sure if this is a good method that i'm using to do this.  Have any thoughts on that or can you point me in the direction to be able to inflate the view

Comment: I do have a fragment activity that does handle all my fragments, this is one of the fragments that it handles